# TypeScript + ES6 Map + Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-shim

I have the following code in TypeScript:

```
export class Config
{
    private options = new Map<string, string>();

    constructor() {
    }

    public getOption(name: string): string {
        return this.options[name]; // <-- This line causes the error.
    }
}
```

And the compiler is giving me this error:

`Error:(10, 16) TS7017: Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type.`

The Map is 'possible' through es6-shim. I am not quite sure what is going on here. Actually this Map confuses me a little. Map is supposed to come from es6-shim which is supposed to implement es6 functionality. But es6 doesn't have static types, right? So, why the Map expects the key/value types as generic arguments? I have seen some people adding a 'noImplicitAny' flag but I want to solve the problem, not ignore it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Retrieving keys from an ES6 Map object is done through the [`Map.prototype.get` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get), **not** using the array operator.

Because all objects in JavaScript are dynamic and can have properties added to them, it is still possible to use the array access operator with a Map object, but it’s wrong—you’re not actually using the Map functionality, you’re just adding arbitrary properties to the instance. You may as well be using `{}` instead of `new Map()` at that point. The TypeScript compiler is trying to tell you so, by warning you that you’re trying to use an index signature that does not exist.

Comment: **TL;DR**: Use `map.get(key)` instead of `map[key]`.

Answer (score 2):

> But es6 doesn't have static types, right? So, why the Map expects the key/value types as generic arguments

These are *compile time types*. Similar how one *can* type an array:

```
let foo = new Array(); // array of any 
let bar = new Array<string>(); // array of strings

foo.push(123); // okay
bar.push(123); // Error : not a string
```

Both lines compile to `new Array()` but one ensures checking on the members

> This line causes the error.

Because the *definition* for `Map` doesn't specify the *return* type of the index signature to be type safe.

Quick Fix:

```
public getOption(name: string): string {
    return this.options[name] as string;
}
```

Comment: This answer is not correct. Map doesn’t not specify a return type of an index signature “to be safe”, it specifies no index signature *at all* because Map objects don’t work that way (they have get/set methods instead).

Answer (score -1):

Try creating interface for options. Something Like,

```
interface IOptions {

[propName: string]: string;

}
```